# How can I get the TransactionID after payment in PayPal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I'm developing a website with MVC and I'm going to manage the payment with PayPal.

After the payment I need the transaction ID but I don't know how can I get it.
Anyone can help me?

```
payRequest.ReturnURL = url + Url.Action("PaymentPayPalOk");
            payRequest.CancelURL = url + Url.Action("PaymentKo");
            payRequest.Amount = Math.Round(model.total, 2);
            payRequest.Commento = string.Format("Ordine: {0}", OrderId);
            payRequest.ReceiverEmail = PayPal.RecipientEmail;
            var payResponse = _payPalService.ProcessPayment(payRequest, Server.MapPath("~/"));
            model.TransactionId = payResponse.PayPalKey;
            if (payResponse.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return Redirect(payResponse.RedirectURL);
            }
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
```

I attached the image of the information that i need

[image]

Comment: What kind of SDK are you using?

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm using SOAP Response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which kind of SDK you're using but normally you find the `TransactionID` in your REST Response at the `related_resources` property of each transaction element in the `id` value.

[image: Example JSON Response]

---

*I recommend you to look up the [PayPal-NET-SDK on github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK). It has a nice and strong community and also a fast response on your issues.*

Comment: It is unclear to me if the marked ID in the question is a seller or buyer Transaction ID. However I'd like to point out that paypal seems to use different IDs for the 'same transaction' depending whether you look from it from the buyer or the seller side. https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Sandbox-Environment/Transaction-Code-vs-Transaction-ID/td-p/1337208 and especially https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Business-Archive/Transaction-ID-mismatch/td-p/425337 where a Moderator clarifies "The system needs different reference points to make these associations within the system."